# How do I run an sql script in mySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql

I just download the SQL workbench and I cannot figure out how to run a simple SQL statement. I know this seems like a simple question but how can this be done. It is not as simple as Microsoft Server.

**Question:
How to run a SQL query?
As long as I am here how do you create a simple database?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not connected to a database go to the home page under database and connect to one and go through the steps

Answer (score 0):

To run Workbench Script File(using shortcut)

```
Modifier+Shift+R
```

The SQL Query panel allows SQL commands to be entered. These may then be executed using the buttons in the toolbar displaying lightning bolts. The leftmost ***`“lightning”`*** button is provided to execute the entire script contained within the SQL Query panel, whilst the second button executes only the currently selected statement.

Output from SQL statement execution appears in a Results panel located beneath the SQL Query panel.

also see this step by step tutorial on [how to run script](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_MySQL_Workbench_to_Execute_SQL_Queries_and_Create_SQL_Scripts)